# How to shutdown a spark application without knowing driver Id via spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, spark-submit

We are using DSE Analytics. 
I am trying to schedule a spark job using crontab , 
via spark-submit. Basically this job should run every night , 
When the job is about to be submitted for subsequent times , the existing application should be killed , I am having trouble finding a way to do it.

Because I am unable to find the application Id of the submitted job or the driver Id so I can shutdown gracefully.

I understand that the Spark Master Web UI can be used to find the Submission Id , but if I am going to setup a cron for this , I can't get the Id from the UI .
Is there a proper way to do this.
We are running DSE 6.7 with Analytics running in a dedicated DC.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you show the command line that you're using to start the job?

Comment: I am using the below command 
dse spark-submit  --class com.spark.Test /home/centos/spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: @zXor I am not sure about dse analytics but if you want these scenario to be handled using shell scripting, I have the algorithm created for this. Let me know if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're running it this way, then the driver is deployed in the `client` mode, meaning that it's executing on your local machine, so you can kill it with just `kill` command. You can find the process ID with something like this

```sh
ps -aef|grep com.spark.Test|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'
```